# D functions returning auto ref

Tags: function, reference, d, return-type

What does the return type auto ref on a function mean? I just don't grok it. I took one of the examples from Ali Çehreli's online book and experimented with adapted it in various ways and looked at the generated assembler from GDC, and I'm still not really any the wiser. (I'm a very experienced asm and C programmer, but new to D.) When might you actually need to use this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto` return functions' primary use case is in a template where the function body changes based on some compile time parameter. `auto ref` just extends that to allowing a `ref` return too. Behold:

```
auto ref foo(string magic)() {
   static if(magic == "use ref") {
     int* x = new int;
     return *x;
   } else {
     return 0;
   }
}

void main() {
        foo!""();
        foo!"use ref"();
}
```

Each unique set of compile time arguments will generate a different function. Those different functions have entirely different code.

This is the function with an empty string:

```
Disassembly of section .text._D3iii15__T3fooVAyaa0_Z3fooFNaNbNiNfZi:

00000000 <_D3iii15__T3fooVAyaa0_Z3fooFNaNbNiNfZi>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
   2:   c3                      ret
   3:   90                      nop
   4:   90                      nop
   5:   90                      nop
   6:   90                      nop
   7:   90                      nop
```

As you can see, it is most trivial - `return 0`. No fancy ref return there. This is the one with `use ref`:

```
Disassembly of section .text._D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNcNfZi:

00000000 <_D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNcNfZi>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   8:   50                      push   eax
   9:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   a <_D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNcNfZi+0xa>
   e:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  11:   5d                      pop    ebp
  12:   c3                      ret
  13:   90                      nop
  14:   90                      nop
  15:   90                      nop
  16:   90                      nop
  17:   90                      nop
```

(the mangled name has the string in it as a hexadecimal string of the ascii (well, it is actually UTF-8, unicode works too!) bytes btw, that 75736520726566 portion - recognize 0x75 as 'u' and 0x66 as 'f'. D mangled names can get ridiculously long, but the pattern is pretty simple to read once you get to know it.)

That code calls `new`, so the body is more complex, but notice that eax is still holding the return value there... the pointer. Now, let's take `ref` out of `auto ref` and recompile the same thing.

The first function, of course, remains the same. The second one changed though:

```
Disassembly of section .text._D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNfZi:

00000000 <_D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNfZi>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   8:   50                      push   eax
   9:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   a<_D3iii29__T3fooVAyaa7_75736520726566Z3fooFNaNbNfZi+0xa>
   e:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
  10:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  13:   5d                      pop    ebp
  14:   c3                      ret
  15:   90                      nop
  16:   90                      nop
  17:   90                      nop
```

See that `mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]`? It is no longer returning the pointer (which, of course, is what `ref` return does under the hood), but now what is pointed by it - a normal, non-ref, value return.

So that's the difference between `auto` return and `auto ref`.

Just for completeness, let's change it to `ref int` and see what happens:

```
$ dmd iii
iii.d(6): Error: constant 0 is not an lvalue
iii.d(11): Error: template instance iii.foo!"" error instantiating
```

Now it is an error to just `return 0` because that isn't a valid `ref`.

The practical use case is that templates may make more complex decisions as to what to do in their body, and thus their return type, based on all kinds of arguments. It might just return whatever type was passed into its arguments, it might check platform version (tho that'd be some ugly code lol), whatever. `auto ref` allows you to cover various cases like that without needing to write separate function signatures (and thus, function bodies) yourself.

Comment: what an excellent answer. Thank you very much. This should be publicised more widely.

Comment: auto ref, the intelligent code-fixer, just-make-it-work feature.

Comment: [off-topic] btw Is this beyond the capabilities of the latest dialects of C++? (I know nothing about C++, only lots of asm and C professionally.)

Comment: You know, I haven't used much C++ for a pretty long time now and haven't kept up with everything... but I think it is moot in C++ because it lacks anything like `static_if` to split a body like this. (it does have the preprocessor, but that wouldn't apply here, it happens before any semantic template stuff). I *think*, not sure, but I think the C++ solution would be to overload two templates and use substitution, etc., to make it work. So, as of my knowledge, C++ can get the result for the function caller, but the function implementation will be a lot uglier than the same in D.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is used when you want the compiler to figure out which type a function will return. For example, both the functions below are the same:

```
uint returnAUint(){
   uint r=256;
   return r;
}
auto function2(){
   uint r=256;
   return r;
}
```

and `ref` means that the function will return a pointer/reference. So `auto ref` is for a function that will return a pointer to a data type that the compiler has to figure out itself.